# PyCharm variable explorer does not display pandas column names with whitespace

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I have this `.xlsx` file I can read successfully by using:

```py
pandas.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name="customers", index_col=0)
```

This works great for most columns but a few with a space between characters like in "profile url". This columns are just missing.

**EDIT:**

This is some code to reproduce the issue:

```py
import pandas as pd

def read_excel(file_name):
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name="customers", index_col=0)
    for entry in df.iterrows():
        print(entry)
    return df


read_excel("test_table.xlsx")
```

And this a example table to use:

```
ID,First,Last,Profile Url
1,foo,bar,www.google.com
2,fake,name,https://stackoverflow.com/
```

This is the value of entry in the first iteration.
Doing so I can the objects **First** and **Last**.

I would expect to see **Profile Url** as well.

[image]

What I learned by preparing this example is that any header written in lowercase will also be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The behavior is not related to any specific file type, it's the case for any dataframe with a space in the column name, regardless of the method with which the dataframe is created.
- Currently there is an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44794) with JetBrains, regarding this behavior.
- The resolution is, fix the columns, by replacing the spaces with another character, such as `'_'`.
- Lowercase column names do not preset the same issue. My guess is there is leading or trailing whitespace in the column name, which can be removed with `.str.strip()`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_no_spaces': [1, 2, 3], 'col with spaces': ['a', 'b', 'c'], ' col_with_leading_trailing_ws ': [4, 5, 6]})

# display(df)
   col_no_spaces col with spaces   col_with_leading_trailing_ws 
0              1               a                               4
1              2               b                               5
2              3               c                               6
```

- Note the columns with spaces, are not available to `View as Series`

[image]

```py
# strip leading and trailing whitespace, and replace spaces in column names with _
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().str.replace('\s+', '_', regex=True)

# display(df)
   col_no_spaces col_with_spaces  col_with_leading_trailing_ws
0              1               a                             4
1              2               b                             5
2              3               c                             6
```

- Note that all columns are now available to `View as Series`

[image]